# How to apply an if statement on the next element of a loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, if-statement

I'm working on a text file representing the elements for a loop:

file.txt

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 7 |
| C | 4 | 4 |

I use the first column as an ID for the rows.

I would like to use a condition to recognize the next element of the loop, and do operation in case it's different (fo example line2 is A but line 3 is B):

```
while read id element1 element2; do
operation1 on $id
operation2 on $id
    if [ $id != $id + 1 ] # where + 1 means "the next line"
    then
    operation3 on $id
    fi
done < path/file.txt
```

I hope that the code above helps to understand what I mean

Comment: Is the `operation3`  going to be called upon reading the last line?

Comment: You could just save last processed id in a variable `$OLD_ID` may be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't; it's conceptually wrong. The next element is only available on the next iteration (i.e. the next read of a line) of the loop. You can however store the `id` of the previous iteration.

```
while read id element1 element2; do
    if [ "$id" != "$previd" ] ; then
        operation3 on $id
    fi
    operation1 on $id
    operation2 on $id
    previd="$id"
done < path/file.txt
```

Which alters the way the first line is processed, but you can test for that too.
Perhaps a better solution would be to use an array and loop through that.

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < file.txt

for i in ${!lines[@]}; do 
    id="${lines[$i]%% *}"
    idnxt="${lines[$i+1]%% *}"
    operation1 on $id
    operation2 on $id
    if [ "$id" != "$idnxt" ] # where + 1 means "the next line" ; 
    then
        operation3 on $id
    fi
done
```

which assumes the separator between the fields in a line is a space and completely ignores what happens to the last line.

Code above may not be completely correct. But it is only there to make a bit clearer what to do.